# get entire document and add new attribute under some condition in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml input like below

```
<items>
    <item id="1" name="aaa" old_level="1" new_level="1"/>
    <item id="2" name="bbb" old_level="2" new_level="3"/>
    <item id="3" name="ccc" old_level="3" new_level="3"/>
</items>
```

I want to copy entire doc and add name of the item of which old_level is different then new_level. note: Only one of items can be different.

my xslt code is like below

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>          
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>       
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/items">
    <xsl:for-each select="/items/item">
        <xsl:variable name="new-level">
            <xsl:value-of select="@new_level"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="old-level">
            <xsl:value-of select="@old_level"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="string($new-level) != string($old-level)">        
            <xsl:variable name="threshold">
                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:copy>      
                <xsl:attribute name="selected_item">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:copy>                     
        </xsl:if> 
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item selected_item="bbb"/>
<items>
   <item id="1" name="aaa" new_level="1" old_level="1"/>
   <item id="2" name="bbb" new_level="3" old_level="2"/>
   <item id="3" name="ccc" new_level="3" old_level="3"/>
</items>
```

what i want to see is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items selected_item="bbb">
   <item id="1" name="aaa" new_level="1" old_level="1"/>
   <item id="2" name="bbb" new_level="3" old_level="2"/>
   <item id="3" name="ccc" new_level="3" old_level="3"/>
</items>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there will definitely be always exactly one such element then it's as simple as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>          
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/items">
        <items selected_item="{item[@new_level != @old_level]/@name}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </items>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If there's a possibility that there's *no* selected item (i.e. no item whose old and new levels are different) then you need a bit of conditional logic to omit the attribute in that case:

```
    <xsl:template match="/items">
        <items>
            <xsl:variable name="selectedItem"
                          select="item[@new_level != @old_level]/@name" />
            <xsl:if test="$selectedItem">
                 <xsl:attribute name="selected_item">
                      <xsl:value-of select="$selectedItem" />
                 </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </items>
    </xsl:template>
```